# is it possible to have load balancer with reverse proxy on apache server?

Tags: apache, centos, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

currently I am having 4 servers as below

A : 191.11.1.100

B : 191.11.1.101

C : 191.11.1.102

D : 191.11.1.103

www.example.com is cent OS server where I have installed apache and I am able to do load balancing of server A and B on the same with help of JKMount but on the same server I want to have reverse proxy for server C and D with reverse proxy string Test and Demo

so that if URL is entered as www.example.com then it should be redirect either of server A and B response should be under www.example.com URL
if www.example.com/Test then request should be redirected to server C and response should be under www.example.com/Test
if www.example.com/Test then request should be redirected to server D and response should be under www.example.com/Demo
[image: httpd conf]

[image: worker properties files]

Comment: can you share your current proxy/balancer configuration

Comment: edit your question please, it will be more readable :)

Comment: @dusan bajic Thank you, added image of both files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible have loadbalancer with reverse proxy

You only need to add node under  tag
as below

ProxyPass /demo http://172.16.XX.XX:9191/Login/
  ProxyPassReverse /demo http://172.16.XX.XX:9191/Login/